# If community would have been a person

Tags: code-golf

Well the [community](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity&sort=revisions) is just a bot. But what if it would have been a person?

Your task is to find what community's reputation might have been if it would have been given reputation for the edits it makes.(simply 2*edits)

This should work for any site, but we would consider PP&CG for this question.

Use any language, even data.stackexchange would work.

As it is code golf, smallest code wins as much reputation I gain+15(via bounty, I will leave 101 for myself :P ).

EDIT: consider all kind of edits that increase reputation.

Comment: What if you have downvotes? Will you give us negative reputation as well?

Comment: Should we count only suggested edits or normal edits (which do NOT increase rep) as well? What about tag wiki edits?

Comment: Why'd you link to history beta?

Comment: @thedoctor my mistake.Please change it to PPCG link.I don't have access to my computer currently.

Comment: @doorknob thanks. I have edited post

Comment: Do we have to consider the cutoff? There is a maximum of reputation that can be gained in this manner. My guess is that on many sites, community would have reached this maximum.

Comment: @TimSeguine Good point. The daily maximum reputation is 200 points, and there is a total of 1000 for each user. ([Source](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation))

Comment: I think the main reason about not having many answers is that you question is not very clear and specific - You still haven't accounted for the max rep gained by suggested edits (1000), and the daily max rep (200).

Comment: @ace I thought the 200 rep cap is un nessesary because community has not crossed the limit on most site(not on codegolf at least) and also that changing it now may in validate already posted answers. from next time onwards I would take due care not to miss anything.Thank you.

Comment: @PatilAditya Should we include the 1 reputation Community has already? (I.e. [num of revisions]*2+1) If so, my answer is the only valid one (so that may be a problem), if not, I can shorten my entry with two chars.

Answer (score 4):

I know URL shorteners are cheaty but since everyone else is using them I probably should.

## Bash, with `bc` and URL shortener: <del>67 62 60 58</del> 54

```bsh
bc<<<`wget x.co/4Ccg3 -qO-|grep -oP "(?<='>)[0-9]+"`*2
```

Downloads the relevant page to STDOUT, then searches for `'>` followed by a sequence of digits - it misuses the fact that in the page's source code, single quotes are only rarely used; in fact the sequence `'>` occurs twice, and only once followed by a number, which is the number of edits. Using the Perl-style lookbehind, the `'>` isn't actually included in the match.

The `-o` option makes `grep` output only the matched string rather than the entire line containing it (there is a `h1` on the same line and I don't want that).

The resulting number of edits is concatenated with `*2` and sent to `bc`.

**@11684 pointed out that you start out with 1 reputation, but the asker clearly forgot that so it's not mentioned in the question (it would break existing answers if it was). If you want to add that in just put in `+1` at the end of the code, adding 2 chars.**

## [SHELF](https://github.com/professorfish/bash-shelf), 36 - doesn't count as the language was created after the question

```bsh
, `W x.co/4Ccg3|t "(?<='>)[0-9]+"`*2
```

SHELF is a golfed version of Bash, like PYG is for Python.

Comment: I'm going to steal your shortened link, as `x.co` is shorter than `goo.gl`. :)

Comment: @11684 i don't mind, i already gave it to Synthetica

Comment: URL shortening, clever ;)

Answer (score 2):

## Python (<s>191</s> <s>181</s> <s>170</s> <s>126</s> 117)

@Henrik: Good idea to use an url shortener. Don't mind if I just borrow yours, do you? Just to kick it off, this will probably get beaten very, very fast ;)

```
i=__import__("urllib2").urlopen("http://x.co/4Ccg3").read();j=i[i.index("<span class='count")+20:];print 2*int(j[:2])
```

Searches for the `<span class='count'>` that contains the amount of reputation the bot has.

Comment: You should be able to remove `community` from the url.

Comment: Er, this doesn't work. `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
`

Comment: @ace Something buggered up somewhere, not sure why. Anyways: it does work now.

Comment: more shorterer: http://x.co/4Ccg3

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (EcmaScript 6 + jQuery) - 80 Characters

```
$.get('/users/-1/?tab=activity&sort=revisions',r=>alert($('.count',r).text()*2))
```

Run it in the JavaScript console on any StackExchange page (although ECMAScript 6 arrow functions are only supported on FireFox at the moment so it will have do be done in that browser until the others catch up) and will get Community's reputation on that domain. So running it on `http://codegolf.stackexchange.com` will get the Code Golf Community's reputation (currently 118) and running it on `http://academia.stackexchange.com/` would get the reputation from that site (currently 162).

Which hopefully answers the

> This should work for any site

bit of the question.

Comment: I feel like using jQuery should add 83532 to the end score

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (with jQuery) - 141

```
$.get('http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/-1/?tab=activity&sort=revisions',function(o){alert($('<a>').html(o).find('.count').html()*2)})
```

**EDIT** : only works if executed from any StackExchange page... or if [same origin policy is disabed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome/6083677#6083677).

If same origin policy is disabled, can be shorten to 96 chars :

```
$.get('http://tinyurl.com/pfmsq8w',function(o){alert($('<a>').html(o).find('.count').html()*2)})
```

Answer (score 1):

***I've included the 1 reputation that you start with!***

## jQuery, 76

```
$a=$("body");$a.load("//x.co/4Ccg3 .count",function(){$a.text($a.text()*2+1)
```

on any page with jQuery and requested by http.

## jQuery, only works on the relevant page - 23

```
$(".count").text()*2+1;
```

The page it runs on is http://goo.gl/JOqzpF.

Answer (score 1):

## StackExchange Data 78 chars

[Click here to run the query](http://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/query/edit/199372)

```
SELECT COUNT(*)*2FROM PostHistory WHERE UserId=-1AND PostHistoryTypeId IN(4,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

## PowerShell (143)

My first ever PowerShell script! Counts the number of revisions and times it by two (very inspired by @Synthetica's Python answer).

```
$s=(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://tinyurl.com/pfmsq8w");(0+($s.Substring($s.IndexOf("s='cou")+10,8) -replace "[^\d]",""))*2
```